# What determines that Fallback Model starts with <block type="page/html" name="root"..>?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme-fallback

What determines that Fallback Model starts with opening page.xml and `<block type="page/html" name="root"..>` ?

I mean, what differ this block from others that make it special, the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a standard configuration, output starts on the Block named root
>   (because it has an output attribute)

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html